# Stream DVD audio through AirPlay

Tags: airplay, quicktime, dvd, vlc

Hi have a Bowers & Wilkins Z2 which supports AirPlay.

When I see DVDs on my MacBook Pro I would like to stream the audio to the speaker.

Is there a way for doing it?

While iTunes provides an icon for AirPlay, the same is not true for QuickTime.

VLC 2.1.0 has a command in the Audio menu (`Audio`->`Audio Device`->`Airplay`) however it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is hold the 'option' key and click the audio icon on the menu bar. A special audio menu will appear, which allows to select the AirPlay device as default audio output.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences → Sound → Output and choose your speakers. Lagging will probably make it unbearable, but maybe you can adjust video/audio sync in VLC.